# Eclipse Juno keyboard shortcuts affecting non- visible window

Tags: eclipse

This is a very strange problem: after working some time with Eclipse Juno and having multiple classes opened, when I Ctrl- V or Ctrl- A, it affects not the selected & visible window/ class, but another one that isnt visible. I hope it's clear what I mean. 
Anyone else experienced this? OS is Mint 13.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem as well, but I'm not sure this is the proper place to ask that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Android Development Tools? If so, there are 2 known bugs about this. One has been fixed in ADT 20, the [other one](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34630) is still open as of ADT 20.0.1.

Comment: Yes, I am. The open one looks like the bug I am experiencing. Thanks for sharing that link.